# Android can't load FragmentActivity from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

I'm following the google android tutorial to get a basic feel of how apps are created but I can't figure out how to implement a tabbed menu bar on the action menu. Following, the first set of tutorials, I can create a basic input form and load the inputted text into a new activity. I then tried to create a new button and link it to an the activity from this tutorial below. I it's an exact copy of google's example

https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Here is my manifest file. I have the original main activity, which is just a form for input and the demo activity which contains the action bar tabbed menu

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.francismitra.myapplication.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/demo_fragment" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CollectionDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/demo_collection" />
    <activity
```

I launch demo activity from the main activity through the following (this always results in the app force closing)

```
public void openDemo(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The DemoActivity.java file is an exact copy from the android developer examples -- I simply updated the package names. CollectionDemoActivity is also an exact copy. I've confirmed that the button attached to openDemo works by setting up a test activity and it launches fine. The app only closes I try to open DemoActivity.

Can someone explain why I can't open this specific activity? I'm trying to implement a design where the main activity has no action bar tabs and another activity can be accessed from the main activity that will have action bar tabs

```
public class DemoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.article_view);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
    // of the app.
    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
    // parent.
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
    // user swipes between sections.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
            // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
            // Tab.
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
        // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
        // listener for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}'

   /**
 * A fragment that launches other parts of the demo application.
 */
public static class LaunchpadSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_launchpad, container, false);

        // Demonstration of a collection-browsing activity.
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.demo_collection_button)
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CollectionDemoActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        // Demonstration of navigating to external activities.
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.demo_external_activity)
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Create an intent that asks the user to pick a photo, but using
                        // FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET, ensures that relaunching
                        // the application from the device home screen does not return
                        // to the external activity.
                        Intent externalActivityIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                        externalActivityIntent.setType("image/*");
                        externalActivityIntent.addFlags(
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                        startActivity(externalActivityIntent);
                    }
                });

        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
                getString(R.string.dummy_section_text, args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
}

}
```

Here are my logs:

```
ddmlib: Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:675)
    at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:342)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:521)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:847)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:815)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:775)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:664)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:46)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:592)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public void openDemo(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DemoActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

}

Remove/ Comment other functionality which causes crash and 
Follow the link:
[Check this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you lost connection with your testing device.
Try to unplug/plug or

`adb kill-server
adb start-server`